# How do you get access to the right island in the lego jurassic world game?

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

We have completed the jurassic park and jurassic world games in the left island. We've even beat jurassic world a second time because we thought it somehow wasn't completed and when we return to the hub where the helicopter is we still don't have access to any of the world's on the right island. I've read where others say you get in the helicopter or the boat at the hub but when we try to get in the helicopter the characters back away like they're scared of the running blades. And there's no boat at the dock to get on. We're at a loss and have no idea how to move on in the game. Can someone please help?